# Losing Session when get request header is too long

Tags: php, session, laravel, request, laravel-5.1

I'm having a problem with my application.
I created a filter panel on which the users can select multiple parameters and then I pass them to a GET request that hits a function inside a controller that returns the results. All this is very basic stuff,  I had no problem implementing this. But my application uses uuids and the request URI gets very long. That results to losing my current session, log out current user and Laravel to generate a new session token.
The URI is something like this:

```
www.domain.com/search?offer_category[]=892b06ac-6552-43ca-9fcd-ba65d4223e7d&offer_category[]=bc66fd8d-1ea9-4968-bee5-8ab9ab665446&offer_category[]=46907770-13d8-4ba1-be33-58f254624860&offer_category[]=6fd45d2b-8dc0-4d8e-a94c-1d3eab86eb0a&offer_type[]=62f23e8b-c22e-43f7-8bf6-8b393e81a1ca&offer_type[]=d33b2a38-50fe-4868-8cfc-9af9ef39d91e&order_by=duration_to&order_dir=asc
```

Why is this happening? Is there a max header character count for GET request? Can I get through this? I don't want to use a POST request, I don't think it's the right way to do a search.

Comment: May want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request). You can increase the size, so it shouldn't be a problem. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) may be helpful.